# Python Regex match character before or after slash

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to write a regex which matches strings based on the following:

- String should not a have space before and after `/`
- String can only have two special characters (`*`, `:`) before or after `/`
- String can have any number of `/` and as longs as there is no space it should be considered as a single match

Sample input looks like

```
Artifacts path 'artifacts_tube/AtomInstall*/**' not found.     // 1 match
</root>                                                        // 0 matches
Failed steps: [<DF2 [D:/Users/work/tmp/assets/dummyfailer]>]   // 1 match
Options : *.* /NS /NC /NDL /COPY:DAT /NP /MT:32 /R:11 /W:30    // 0 matches
Copy Dir: D:/Users/tempdir/tmp8fo -> D:/Users/tempdir/tmpj7xj  // 2 matches
```

I have a simple regex but it does not meet all of the above criteria
`\S*\/\S*`. Output for my regex

```
Artifacts path 'artifacts_tube/AtomInstall*/**' not found.     // 1 match
</root>                                                        // 1 match
Failed steps: [<DF2 [D:/Users/work/tmp/assets/dummyfailer]>]   // 1 match
Options : *.* /NS /NC /NDL /COPY:DAT /NP /MT:32 /R:11 /W:30    // 8 matches
Copy Dir: D:/Users/tempdir/tmp8fo -> D:/Users/tempdir/tmpj7xj  // 2 matches
```

Comment: why `</root>` should not be matched? It does not violates your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I need to re-word by second condition to say that a string can only have `*` and `:` as special characters.

Comment: So e.g. "/a:/:*/a" should give a match? If it's Windows pathnames you want to match, you should clarify that.

Comment: and why `/NDL` should not matched? Just because it does not look like a path does not mean that it will be excluded from result magically :D You need to define what _is_ path.

Comment: "/a:/:*/a" would give a match as there is no space or no special characters outside the approved list before the first `/`

Comment: Since in the above examples `/NDL` has a space before the `/` it should not match.

Comment: Oops that's correct, I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for (it allows `:` and `*` to occur anywhere in the path) but I think you can achieve your goal with it.

```
(?!\/[^:*])(?![^:*]\/)[\w\/*:]*\/[\w\/*:]*
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VWwzq/3)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for what you need

```
[*:](?!\s)\/[\s]*[:*]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/nI18g9/1